# Good warrior one handed sword strength weapons

Tags: dark-souls

I've researched some good warrior strength swords and the results seem to lead to the Zweihander or the Man-serpent Greatsword. I really don't like playing the game two handed and I would just like to know some good one-handed strength swords. What are some good one-handed strength swords?

Answer (score 3):

Every Weapon in Dark Souls can be one-handed, and as such there are no such thing as "One handed swords". You need 24 Str and 10 Dex to one hand A Zweihander, and 24 Str to one-hand a Man-serpent Greatsword (Assuming this is Dark-Souls 1). These would make good one-handed swords for a warrior.

Comment: I can agree that there is logic behind these suggestions that I can agree with, but at the same time, The Longsword is also perfectly viable, and even the Drake Sword. As it is, the question is not focused enough for a (as in one) viable answer - any answer is perfectly viable, and just as nonviable.